# Help with understanding a "broken" 手紙文

Tags: archaic-language, reading-comprehension

A letter from a story, where a character (又八) elopes with a woman (お甲), with both writing a letter each to the man's betrothed (お通, who 又八 abandoned with said woman) (お甲's letter quoted full, for context):

> べつの文、ご覧なされ候わば、多言には及ぶまじと思われ候えど、証のため、私よりも認めまいらせ候。又八どの、此度、御縁の候て、当方の養子にもらいうけ候に就いては、おん前様のこと、懸念のようにみえ候まま、左候ては、ゆく末、双方の不為故、事理おあかし申し候て、おもらい申候。何とぞ、以後は又八どのの事、御わすれくだされたく先は斯ように迄、一筆しめし参らせ申そろ。かしこ。お甲。お通さま

My rough 'understanding' of part I'm struggling with):

…懸念しているようだから、そうして、ゆく末（消息）、双方（あなたと又八）の不為ゆえ（の為にならないから）、（又八には）その理由を彼の手紙に明らかにしてもらって、？？（あなたにはその手紙をうけてもらった？）

Does 不為故 imply 消息を明かさないと損になる? I.e. not giving reason would be bad for both, or have I misunderstood? Is 申す here used in polite sense to describe the actions of man/his betrothed?

[Story link](http://www.aozora.gr.jp/cards/001562/files/52396_49781.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not broken, but a standard style for any kind of letters mainly used until Meiji era (候文).

> おん前様のこと、懸念のようにみえ候まま、左候ては、ゆく末、双方の不為故、事理おあかし申し候て、おもらい申候。

is in present-day Japanese:

> あなた様のことを気にかけているようにみえますので、こうですと今後お互いのためになりませんから、事情をお明かしいたしまして、（又八を）おもらいいたします。

The long-trailing sentence isn't a bad style but is also a characteristic of pre-Meiji writing style, where a sentence could continue as long as a paragraph.

不為 is saying that it'll cause harm if the relationship between 又八 and お通 remains unsettled.

Notes:

- 申す is a common 謙譲語 in this style that corresponds to today's いたす.
- 候 is, likewise, a 丁寧語 that is today's （であり）ます.
- 左【さ】's kanji is ateji, the word is not "left" but "so". 左候 means こうです "it is so".

Comment: 「[まま](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/209473/meaning/m0u/)」にこんな意味もあったんですね…

Comment: @naruto OPさんは正しく訳してたので説明しませんでしたが、辞書にはちゃんと載ってるはずです

Answer (score 3):

I may be wrong, but here's my understanding:

- 左候ては、 ＝ このようでは／これでは *if this continues, if that is the case* ([ては = conditional](http://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A6%E3%81%AF))
- ゆく末、 ＝ 将来 *in the future*
- 双方の不為故、 ＝ お互いのためになりませんので *there will be no benefit to either of us, therefore ...*
- 事理おあかし申し候て、おもらい申候。 ＝ 事情を明らかにさせていただきます。 *let me take the liberty of clarifying our situation.*

<del>**EDIT**: So I felt that 「事理おあかし申し候て、おもらい申候」 part was no more than a roundabout and redundant humble expression. A more 'literal' translation would be... maybe 「事情を明らかにさせてもらわせられ申し上げます」 or something like that. Honestly, I have no idea if the original sentence is broken or not as a traditional 候文.</del>

**EDIT 2**: See broccoli forest's answer for the last part (interpretation of おもらい申候).